# SSD is not bootable

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, asus-laptop, dell-vostro

I have looked in many solutions and none seem to work, so I am resorting to possibly duplicating. I recently bought a new desktop (Dell Vostro) to replace a failing ASUS laptop. In the old laptop I had a Samsung SSD 850 EVO, which I plugged into the new desktop. It can be seen and browsed from Windows, but the boot manager does not detect it - even though it booted properly from my old laptop. Both are Windows 10. Here are the things I tried from other solutions:

- Disable the m2 device so that Windows installs what is needed on the older device. This only resulted in a BIOS failure saying it could not detect anything to boot.
- Disable secure mode. Nothing
- Set the bootmanager to display at startup - only the one Windows 10 is listed
- Played with changing from RAID to AHCI and whatnot, but I was a bit unsure of messing something up in that regard. I think this could be the issue (as the new PC is set up as RAID), but I still can't figure that out...and am not entirely sure.
- Currently I am looking into changing the older from MBR to GPT...Could that be it, or am I chasing the wrong lead?

Also, I have looked at Disk Management, both disks are listed as healthy:

- New disk: Healthy(Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition)

  - M.2 PCIe SSD
- Old disk: Healthy(Active, Primary Partition)

Additional information to answer comments:

- There is no option for legacy mode boot, and as such I believe it is ONLY UEFI. I cannot find a way to get to legacy boot mode at all from BIOS...

[image: Disk Management as requested]

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it can be the drive mode (RAID/AHCI) but also the installation mode (UEFI vs Legacy/BIOS).

Comment: Did you configure your firmware to work as UEFI/GPT mode or Legacy BIOS?

Comment: How about a screenshot of Disk Management instead?

Comment: There is only UEFI as far as I can tell - added more details to the post

Comment: I think my latest update about the old disk being MBR is on the right track from my other findings...I am looking to backup the disk so I can try to convert to GPT and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Converting to GPT will not be enough -- EFI needs a different type of bootloader to be installed (note the "EFI System Partition" on your new disk).

Comment: @user1686 So is there any way to reformat the disk without having to wipe it? (Noting I will still back it up just in case)

Comment: If you have a USB stick with a recent version Win10 installer, you could try the mbr2gpt tool that comes with it? I have not tried it yet. Besides that there's also a manual method (involving gdisk on a Linux USB stick *and* bcdboot from a Win10 one), and I think I had written an answer about it a while ago...

Comment: @JustinPihony: See if https://superuser.com/questions/1649574/computer-bios-boot-with-uefi answers that question.