# Making PC Windows 11 ready. Secure boot disabled message

Tags: mbr, gpt, tpm, windows-11

I am making my personal pc Windows 11 ready because I need to get to know it for my work.
So I tried the PC Healthy Check from MS, to check if my PC is Windows 11 ready.
I get the massage 'PC must support secure boot'.

To get this message to go away I tried multiple things.

- TPM 2.0 and Secure boot is enabled in BIOS.
- I have set most settings to UEFI only.

I found out that:
When I turn Boot Device Control to UEFI only, windows won't boot.
my SSD is MBR not GPT.

What do I need to do to get PC Healthy Check, to say my PC supports W11? Or well see that Secure Boot is enabled.

[device info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC6Ht.png)
[boot device control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJigs.jpg)
[secure boot enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXRQP.jpg)

Comment: This remains a question that cannot be answered with any assurance (zero assurance at this point) until Microsoft puts out clear information and a near to production version.

Comment: Oh god what a bag of hurt MS is causing with these stupid requirements for secure boot and TPM.

Comment: Yes, and that is why I say no assurance about what might happen. This machine of mine (Windows 10 Pro preloaded) with Secure Boot, TPM 2, DirectX 12, WDDM 2.1 does not qualify for Windows 11 !!!

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to do to get PC Healthy Check, to say my PC supports W11?

You can run MBR2GPT and convert your installation to be compatible with UEFI only mode.  You should as with any changes to your partitions make a full backup of your system.  Full instructions can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1649574/computer-bios-boot-with-uefi/1649577#1649577)

> Or well see that Secure Boot is enabled.

Secure Boot is a UEFI mode-only feature. You will be unable to upgrade to Windows 11 without performing a clean install unless you use MBR2GPT and enable Secure Boot.

The alternative is when Windows 11 is released, you can format everything on the disk while in UEFI mode and install Windows 11 provided your system meets all other requirements.

In clear and precise language, Microsoft has indicated that the requirements for Windows 11 Insider Preview builds are not identical to that of the RTM Windows 11 build. Systems that install Windows 11 Insider Preview builds that ultimately do not meet the final Windows 11 RTM minimum requirements will be forced to downgrade to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have BIOS booting. Secure Boot only works with pure UEFI (CSM disabled). This isn’t something you can just switch though.

Depending on your current hard drive layout, you may be able to use [Microsoft’s MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) tool. You can use it directly with `/allowFullOS`.

If the tool cannot do it, it get’s a lot harder. You could just reinstall Windows.

Or you can try it manually. Remember to back up. You need a Windows setup USB/DVD, and also a proper partition tool (like `gdisk`) that can convert from MBR to GPT while keeping the partitions.

1. Delete BIOS boot partitions (small, active), possibly also the recovery and/or reserved partitions if there is less than 100 MB of space.
2. Convert to GPT, keeping other partitions
3. Create new EFI System Partition (at least 100 MB), format it using FAT32
4. Enable UEFI, disable legacy booting
5. Start Windows Setup, bring up Command Prompt using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
6. Identify the drive letter of the Windows partition (possibly C:) and EFI System Partition (you can use `diskpart` or other tool to help)
7. Use `bcdboot c:\windows /s h: /f UEFI` where `c:\windows` is the Windows folder and `h:` is the EFI System Partition