# Can't see HDD after enabling Secure Boot for Windows 11

Tags: windows, bios, secure-boot

Windows 11 is coming out, and according to the diagnostic tool I need to enable Secure Boot and TPM in order to upgrade. The TPM part was easy enough, however, the Secure Boot doesn't really work.

I have an Asus PRIME X570-P motherboard, with a Ryzen 9 CPU, and a 1TB 970 EVO NVMe.

In my BIOS in the CSM menu I changed all input to UEFI (that's what I read was needed in order to get a check for the Secure Boot in Windows 11). However, the issue is, that now I can't boot to any of my hard drives. I can see them in the main menu of my BIOS, but nothing is listed as a boot option.

I am not quite sure what to do here ?

Comment: Sounds like you installed windows 10 with Legacy boot enabled, this means, you won’t be able to enable secure boot (and thus enable UEFI mode) unless you convert to GPT.  Can you confirm Windows was installed in Legacy mode? [edit] your question with the required information to answer your question

Comment: Relevant question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1659547/secure-boot-ueif-windows-11/1659569#1659569) and likely a duplicate