# Computer keeps booting into BIOS when disabling legacy BIOS and enabling UEFI

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, windows-11

I am trying to install Windows 11 and it requires my machine to have a secure boot functionality. For that, I need to enable UEFI for the devices and/or disable legacy BIOS.
I am trying to do that in the BIOS by disabling 'Launch CSM' and changing 'Boot Device Control' to 'UEFI Only' from UFEI and Legacy'. When I do any combination of those two, the machine will always boot into BIOS instead of booting. It's as if it doesn't like the new settings. The MOBO is ASUS ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO and the BIOS is Mega Trends.

My boot drive is a Corsair Neutron Series NX500 on PCI-E. There was a message in the BIOS at one point that mentioned I need a signed UEFI driver for storage devices.
I don't know if the drive has it or not. How to find out? Do I need it for the secure boot?
If it's missing, could this be the reason the machine is booting into the BIOS?

**Update:**
Windows 10 was installed with CSM enabled.

[image]

Comment: If you installed the OS while the CSM was enabled you are probably being dropped into the firmware menu because you no longer have any bootable drives and it's basically telling you to set one up. Secure boot requires UEFI, and Windows requires a GPT partitioned boot disk to boot from a UEFI system. You'll either have to install from scratch or go through the pain of (with CSM enabled) using [`mbr2gpt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/mbr2gpt-tool-test-guidance) and then switching off the CSM and hoping that it worked.

Comment: Looking for info on another W11 question on ASUS I found in their documentation advice to disable CSM. Unfortunately I'm not on the same system so don't have the link for you.

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 with CSM enabled or disabled.  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secure Boot / UEIF / WIndows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1659547/secure-boot-ueif-windows-11)

Comment: I am not planning to convert the drive to GPT and hope it works because if it doesn't and the machine doesn't boot anymore, I might be sorry I started the process. I don't need Windows 11 for now.